# Error in sending Python API request from AWS Lambda python function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I am trying send a POST request from AWS python lambda function but getting following error while sending:

> [ERROR] ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host=
> ********************s3-website.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f69fdfbda90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out'))
> Traceback (most recent call last):

![Response]

I tried with the following code:

```
import json
import uuid
import datetime
import re
import base64
import requests
import httpx
import asyncio
def lambda_handler(event,context):

    INVENTORY_CP_OPERATION_URL="************.s3-website.ap-south- 
                 1.amazonaws.com/"
    message={
       "email":"*******@********.com",
       "password":"123456"
        }
    result=requests.post(**************,json=message)
    return "success".
```

Comment: Is your AWS Lambda function connected to a VPC? If so, is there a particular reason for doing so? If not, disconnect the Lambda function from the VPC and try again. Let us know what happens.

Comment: Yes sir, by disconnecting the VPC, its working fine.

Comment: Does that solve your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your `Connection timed out`, it would seem that your AWS Lambda function is having difficulty connecting to the Internet.

When an AWS Lambda function is ***NOT* connected to a VPC**, it has direct access to the Internet.

However, when a Lambda function ***IS* connected to a VPC**, it only has Internet access if the Lambda function is connected to a private subnet and there is a NAT Gateway in a public subnet.

Therefore, if the function does not require access to any resources in a VPC (eg Amazon RDS databases), then it is best to **disconnect it from the VPC**.

Comment: Yes, we are connecting VPC to the subnets still not getting internet access.